# Why isn't my if statement behaving as expected

Tags: matlab

I want to use `t` to calculate `s`, but my code complains about the variable `s` being undefined. Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
a=1;
b=2;
t=input('输入');

if (-100<t<0) 
      T=t+100
      c1=20
      s=T*t
end
fprintf('输出%f\n',s)
```

Comment: `s` appears to be local to the `if` statement.

Comment: Because `s` is out of scope? `s` is defined inside the if statement and can't be accessed outside. Define it outside the if statement.

Comment: I had did it ,but if I set s = 1,then I type t=-10,in this code ,the s should equal T*t,however I get s=1 every time,no matter which number t is

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because the contents of your `if` block are never executed (and `s` is only defined if you execute the contenst of the `if` block). This is due to the way that the logical expression `-100 < t < 0` is evaluated. Rather than checking if `t` is between `-100` and `0`, it is the equivalent of the following

```
(-100 < t) < 0;
```

Which is never going to evaluate to `true` since `-100 < t` can either be `true` (1) or `false` (0) *but* both `1` and `0` are *not* `< 0`

To check that `t` is in the range `(-100, 0)`, you will instead want to break up the conditional into two pieces and combine them with a logical `and` (`&&`).

```
if t > -100 && t < 0
```

Also, you'll want to be sure to set `s` to some default value so that if `t` is outside of the specified range, you won't get the error that you're seeing

```
s = NaN;

if t > -100 && t < 0
    T = t + 100;
    c1 = 20;
    s = T * t;
end
```